# How to create a Button from code in WPF and Python?

Tags: python, wpf, button, visual-studio-2013, ironpython

I need to build multiple buttons, but I can't display any button! this is my code of a WPF application with IronPython 2.7..

I've tried this in two different ways, with "Grid.Children.Add(button)" and without that but anything displays..

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" 
        x:Name="NewWindow" Height="564.22" Width="993.2">

    <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0,0,75.2,92.4">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
        <Button Content="Create a Button from code" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Margin="712,418,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" Height="61"
         Click="CreateButtons_Click"/>     
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CODE:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("IronPython.Wpf.dll")
clr.AddReferenceByPartialName("PresentationCore")
clr.AddReferenceByPartialName("PresentationFramework")
clr.AddReferenceByPartialName("WindowsBase")
clr.AddReferenceByPartialName("IronPython")
clr.AddReferenceByPartialName("Microsoft.Scripting")

import wpf 
from System.Windows import Application, Window, Controls
from System.Windows.Forms import Form, Button

class NewWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'NewWindow.xaml')

    def CreateButtons_Click(self, sender, e):
        self.myButton = Button()
        self.myButton.Name="boton1"
        self.myButton.Text="prueba"
        self.myButton.Size = Size(75,23)
        self.myButton.Location = Point(0,0)
        #Add to grid
        self.grid.Children.Add(self.myButton)
```

That shows an error:

> expected UIElement, got Button

If I skip that error and erase the line **self.grid.Children.Add(self.myButton)**, it doesnt get an error, but doesnt show any button either.

How i can show my button in there by python code? *(New at python and wpf)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what was the problem!! (So easy i can't beieve it!)

The error of UIElement was because (I didnt know that there was two kind of buttons, im sorry!) I was importing **Button** from **System.Windows.Forms** and the correct button has to be imported from **System.Windows.Controls**

Nice day, everybody!